# Negative value range for Trackbar in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, trackbar

I am trying to include negative values in the range of the Trackbar of cv2.createTrackbar. But each time I run the script, the negative values are not considered.

How could I include the negative values?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from cv2 import CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE

def nothing(x):
   pass

cv2.namedWindow('image', flags = CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

cv2.createTrackbar('val1','image',-50,500, nothing)
```

This resets from 0 to 500, instead of staying at -50. How could I keep it from -50 to 500?

Comment: You can't. Please read the [doc](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#gaf78d2155d30b728fc413803745b67a9b): _"The minimal position is always 0."_

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by Alejandro Silvestri, you can actually do this with `setTrackbarMin`

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from cv2 import CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE

def nothing(x):
   pass

cv2.namedWindow('image', flags = CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

cv2.createTrackbar('val1', 'image', 0, 500, nothing) #<-- the '0' here is the default value

cv2.setTrackbarMin('val1', 'image', -50)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not do this. The issue has discussed on [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/9403).

However, you can go to the source code to change it. The guide is [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/9498). It seems to work for a lot of people.

Comment: Fixed?  I setTrackbarMin to a negative value, and it worked!  Of course, it would be better to do this directly in createTrackbar.