# Error: `Bad trackbar maximal value in function 'cvSetTrackbarPos'` on macOS for values below 0

Tags: python, macos, opencv, slider, interactive

on macOS, when trying to define a slider with OpenCV, like that:

```py
cv2.createTrackbar('Slider_val_min', 'image', -100, 100, empty_callback)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) /Users/runner/work/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window_cocoa.mm:440: error: (-211:One of the arguments' values is out of range) Bad trackbar maximal value in function 'cvSetTrackbarPos'
```

For the same code, this is not the case on Linux machine (Ubuntu `18.04`), where values below `0` are allowed for the sliders.

Also on macOS, when I tried values of `0` and above everything worked, i.e., for example:

```py
cv2.createTrackbar('Slider_val_min', 'image', 0, 100, empty_callback)
```

Tested with OpenCV `4.5.5` and `4.6.0`.

Python version `Python 3.8.9`.

Answer (score 0):

The minimal value for `createTrackbar` (and slider position) is always `0`, see: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52225026/negative-value-range-for-trackbar-in-opencv) and [this documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#gaf78d2155d30b728fc413803745b67a9b).

It turns out that on Linux (Ubuntu), if you set a cursor position to a negative value, it is automatically (and silently) set to `0`, and no error is thrown to the user.

So, I misunderstood issue. Nevertheless the implementation differs between Ubuntu and macOS. The former is not throwing error (but silently adjusting the position), while the latter will not allow you to run the program with a negative slider position value.

Comment: OpenCV is planning to replace the entire "highgui" module, and its various system-specific backends, with something cross-platform like OpenGL. progress is unclear. https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/OE-24.-Module-HighGUI